# SpinBox up and down indicator not positioned as expected

Tags: qt, qml

According to the docs for [SpinBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/qml-qtquick-controls2-spinbox.html) indicators are placed on the left and right of the value itself.

So this code:

```
SpinBox {
    value: 50
}
```

Should give this output:

[image]

Now when I run this on Manjaro with Qt 6.2.3 I instead get this output:

[image]

Why It does not show what is expected like in the docs?

Do I need to override `up.indicator` / `down.indicator` to change the whole style?

Comment: It's possible it's using a different [style](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-styles.html) than you expect. It's probably using the Fusion style.

Comment: You are right. I checked it with `qDebug() << QQuickStyle::name();` it is fusion. I totally forget that these elements can change that much with style...

Answer (score 0):

To get this output you should be using `version >= 2.0` of `QtQuick.Controls`.

Comment: Im definetly doing that. I do `import QtQuick.Controls` under 6 which automatically should take the latest version. The issue seems to be in the used style which seems to be on linux fusion.

Comment: My mistake, I didnt read that you are using Qt6, in Qt5 you should add the version after the import.